# Is there a way to make Puppet to run a Jenkins job after a successful deployment?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, puppet

We have a Jenkins CI server that builds our application's war file from SVN whenever it detects a check-in, after a successful build we use a Jenkins job that allows us to manually deploy the application, internally it will run puppet to move the war and restart the container if needed.

In the other hand, we have a Jenkins job that builds a maven project which contains a set of soapui functional tests for the REST API contained in our application. Of course, those tests require the application to be deployed in the server before they execute.

The tests are run with a maven command like this:

```
mvn test
```

What I want is to make puppet to trigger the Jenkins job execution after it deploys successfully the war, how can this be accomplished?

We are using a manifest similar to the one used here http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2010/04/29/deploying-tomcat-applications-puppet

Basically the deployment is being done by this definition:

```
define tomcat::deployment($path) {

  include tomcat
  notice("Establishing http://$hostname:${tomcat::tomcat_port}/$name/")

  file { "/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/${name}.war":
    owner => 'root',
    source => $path,
  }

}
```

I think I can just chain an exec inside that manifest and run a CLI command or call the Jenkins REST interface using curl as Slav suggests in his answer

Comment: Did you check [`subscribe` and `notify`](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/ordering.html#notify-and-subscribe)?

Comment: Could you add the puppet code?

Comment: Yes, Puppet is most definitely able to do that. It's not at all clear what you are specifically asking. Can you elaborate your question, as utrecht asks?

Comment: @Felix, the question is simple, "how to run a Jenkins build job from puppet", I think Slav's answer is what I am looking for

Comment: That question has layers. Slav told you how to trigger Jenkins from the command line. If that is what you needed to know, then Puppet is only an implementation detail. Other questions that could have been inferred include "How to run a custom command from Puppet" or "How to make an `exec` resource sync at the very end of a Puppet run", "How to make Puppet trigger a command only if another one ran successfully", "Is there a way to use a Jenkins API from Puppet". The list probably goes on.

Comment: You are right, I wanted to keep the question simple. I will add more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins can be triggered [**through the CLI**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI). Go to your server in the browser to address `http://<your-jenkins-server/cli` for a full list of commands you can call from CLI.

You can also trigger Jenkins through **[HTTP API calls](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API)**. You don't need anything more than `wget` for that.